# How to obtain the list's index that contain same items in another list?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a list of lists and another separate list, I need to check if the items of the second list are in any list of the list of lists *in the same order* and return the indices of such sublists.

For example:

```
lst=[['ahmad','a',5],['ahmad','b',6],['ahmad','x',4],['Emme','b',5],['Emme','b',4]]
```

and `lst_2=['ahmad','b']`,`lst_3= ['b','ahmad']`.

The desired result:

In the case of lst_2:

```
True
1
```

As for lst_3:

```
False
```

I tried the following line to check if the separate list is in the nested list or not, but the order wasn't considered in the result:

```
any(set(lst_2) <= set(l) for l in lst)

True

any(set(lst_3) <= set(l) for l in lst)

True
```

Comment: Is the order relevant or not? it's not clear to me. And if it is important, is it the order of appearance that is important or the actual index of items?

Comment: @Olivier Melançon thank you for your reply, I edited the Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `set` will for sure not preserve the order as sets are unordered.

Instead, I suggest traversing the list and treating the sublist as a stack from which you pop an element everytime there is a match. If the stack is empty at any time, then you got an ordered sublist.

The use of a `deque` allows to pop from the left of `sublst` in *O(1)*.

### Code

```
from collections import deque

def is_ordered_sublist(sublst, lst):
    sublst = deque(sublst)
    for x in lst:
        if not sublst:
            # return True early if the stack is empty
            return True

        if x == sublst[0]:
            sublst.popleft()

    return not sublst
```

### Examples

```
print(is_ordered_sublist([1, 2, 3], [1, 9, 2, 9, 3, 9])) # True

print(is_ordered_sublist([1, 2, 3], [1, 9, 3, 9, 2, 9])) # False
```

### Recovering sublist indices

You can then use the above function with a list-comprehension and `enumerate` to recover corresponding indices.

```
lst=[['ahmad','a',5],['ahmad','b',6],['ahmad','x',4],['Emme','b',5],['Emme','b',4]]

lst_2=['ahmad','b']

indices = [i for i, l in enumerate(lst) if is_ordered_sublist(lst_2, l)]

print(indices) # [1]
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but you consider a list as a single list not nested list

Comment: @AhmadSuliman I am unsure what you mean, the last lines apply to the input format you provided. If your lists contain nested lists and you need some additional behaviour, please include that in the question. I also added more details in the last section as you might have overlloked it.